# convert a string to type double produces 0.0 instead of a supposed value

Tags: ios, string, xcode, double, uilabel

I am trying to convert a string to type double using Xcode. I've tried some methods I've seen on stack, but my results aren't properly coming out.

[image: example]

In the image above, I am trying to add a tax of 10% to the button Total Cost. in this example it is $35. So the tax $3.50 and the total would be $38.50 The code I use allows me to get the double, but it is only set as 0.0 instead of what should be coming up. I am fetching this number that is stored in firebase and setting it as my money label.

```
  var moneyLabel: UILabel = {
         let label = UILabel()
         label.text = "$"
         label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20)
         label.numberOfLines = 0
         return label
     }()

func setupViews() {

    let post = notification?.poster
    let cost = post?.cost
    let priceString = cost != nil ? "$\(cost!)" : "N\\A"

        self.moneyLabel.text = priceString
        self.moneyLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20)
        self.moneyLabel.textColor = UIColor.black
        configureButtonToSetPrice()
}

    func configureButtonToSetPrice() {
    let priceString = "$\(moneyLabel)"
    let myFloat = (priceString as NSString).doubleValue
    let withTax = "\(myFloat * 0.10 + myFloat)"
    Pay.setTitle("Total Cost \(withTax)", for: .normal)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding $ to priceString is the issue. Due to this the conversion fails and it returns 0.0. Here's the working code.

```
func configureButtonToSetPrice() {
    var moneyLabel: String = "35"
    let myFloat = (moneyLabel as NSString).doubleValue
    let withTax = "\(myFloat * 0.10 + myFloat)"
    print("Total Cost $\(withTax)")
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for your answer! I need the $ in front of the floart with tax is there a way for me to add this?

Comment: Note that I've added the $ to the Total cost. You can add $ after the conversion and not before.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, It does produce the correct output in the console, but what I am trying to do is pass that specific $35 label abover the stars into the button title. I understand that taking the $ away from the original priceString helps with an issue, but is there a way I could accomplish passing whatever number is above the stars and updating it to be a double inside of the buttonTitle?

Comment: Did you figure it out?